# CLOC for difference between two versions of source code by include only "c/c++","h" extensions an exclude other file extension

Tags: cloc

When Cloc --diff   command is executed, it lists differences between all the extensions.
Source code consists c,h,xml,yaml files. Can we get the diff for only specific extensions like ".c",".cpp",".h"?

Provides difference for all extension types

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The `--include-ext` switch lets you define the subset of extensions to consider, ref https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc#options- .

`--include-ext=c,cpp,h` should do what you have in mind.